# Algorithm for Determining Maximum Size for Squares in a Rectangle

Tags: geometry, area, programming

I'm trying to create a program to draw a specific number of equally-sized squares within a rectangle. I want to set my squares' sizes to the maximum size possible while still fitting within a rectangle. Empty space is fine so long as the squares can't get any larger by breaking into a new row.

Here is an illustration of the desired result of the program with square count values 1-5:
[image]

So far, I've successfully found the different permutations for the possible number of columns/rows based on square count. Here's an example using a square count of 4 of the permutations that can contain 4 squares:

```
{rows: 1, columns: 4}
{rows: 2, columns: 2}
{rows: 2, columns: 3}
{rows: 3, columns: 2}
{rows: 3, columns: 3}
{rows: 4, columns: 1}
```

Once I have the permutations, how do I determine which one will allow for the maximum square size within the dynamically-sized rectangle? Is there a way to use the area perhaps?

Please let me know if you have any questions or if I can make something clearer. Thank you!

*My apologies, I am not very familiar with mathematical notation, so please know this if posting any. I will do my best to research anything posted, but I may have follow-up questions. Thanks!*

Comment: It is not clear why in the last case you do not have 8. If there is no limit on square side length than there is no limit.

Comment: @Moti Thank you for the response. Do you mean in the last example where there are 5 squares in the rectangle? If so, there are only 5 because the square count is 5 and that is the maximum size the squares can be while maintaining the 1:1 square aspect ratio. All squares will be the same size and there are 5 total. Please let me know if it's clear.

Comment: @DrPontchartrain I'd suggest this : if the measures of the sides of the squares aren't relatively prime, take their GCD (greatest common divisor) as the side of the square. If the dimensions are relatively prime, take the side of the square to be one unit. These apply if you want no empty space.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically sized rectangle with length $l$ and width $w$.  The largest possible square would have side length $s=\min(l,w)$ (That is the lesser of the length and width)

For programming purposes (depending on the need) it would be easiest to set width and define length as some multiple ($a$) of width. For Example: $w=5$ and $l=7.5$ and $l=aw\implies a=\frac{l}{w}=7.5\div 5=1.5$. Then you can use the $a$ value to determine several things:
If $0<a<1$ then $w>l$ (largest possible square $s=l$);  If $a=1$ then $w=l$ (starting rectangle is square);  If $a>1$ then $w<l$ (largest possible square $s=w$).

$a$ can also be used to determine how many rows/columns of a specific sized square will fit.  If $n$ represents the number of squares desired then you can use a loop to determine if the largest squares possible will fit in a row/column (note: if you force length to always be longer than width it will simplify your programming so that you don't have to consider rows vs. columns)  For example, If we want 7 squares in the rectangle $w=5$ and $l=7.5$ then since $a=1.5$, then $7*1.5>l$ so we consider squares of side length smaller than 1.5.  If we reach an even divisor $k$ (where $k$ is an integer greater than 1) of 1.5 (i.e. $1.5\div 2=.75$, $1.5\div 3=.5$, etc.) then you must account for $k$ rows of squares.  I recommend coming up with some minimum significant digit with which to reduce the square's side length $s$ in the loop.

There are more advanced mathematical approaches to this problem, but purely from a programming perspective, there is some value in keeping it simple.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand some of your explanation but I lost understanding when you began describing the loop.

"we consider squares of side length smaller than 1.5. " Do you mean squares from the permutations or is this method just using the divisor method you described?

"reach an even divisor k." How do we reach this? Do you mean the divisor's sign or do you mean it returns an integer?

"minimum significant digit with which to reduce the square's side length  in the loop" What would the function look like?

Comment: Forgive me for not being able to explain this in mathematical notation, but I have created this program in Javascript to demonstrate where I am with my understanding of your explanation.
https://codepen.io/blastframe/pen/QWEZxrj?editors=1111

Comment: You have the gist of what I was getting at.  I have limited familiarity with JavaScript so not sure what loops are available.  You used for loops in your code.  I was thinking in terms of "do-while" or "do-until" loops.  As you're decreasing your square side length $s$ by $0.1$, you want the program to notice if your side length reaches an integer divisor of the width and/or length.  (i.e. If $s\leq w\div 2$, then we need to consider $2$ rows of squares instead of just one....If $s\leq w\div 3$ then $3$ rows must be considered....If $s\leq w\div k$ then $k$ rows must be considered)

Comment: Please disregard this comment if it confuses the issue for you.  But you could also approach the problem from the rectangle side first....What is largest fit for 1 square? (covered already above) .  What is largest fit for 2 Squares? (compare length and width.  if $l\geq 2w$ then $s=w$ but if $w<l<2w$ then $s=l \div 2$).  What is largest fit for $n$ squares? (if $l\geq n\timesw$ then $s=w$ but if $(n-1)\times w<l<n\times w$ then $s=l \div n$...Again need some checkpoint for when new rows become an option like {if $s\leq w\div k$}.  $k$ could be incremental.  Once we attain $s \leq kw$ -> $k$++